Configure NAT Router Cisco 1941

I have this scenario where the hosts on the internal side of the network access the internet through the public IP using NAT. As shown, I have a server with XAMPP installed, which an external network host can access through the public IP. However, I'm encountering an issue where, if an internal network host (e.g., 192.168.1.10) tries to view the website hosted on the XAMPP server, it only loads when I enter the server's IP (192.168.1.4). If I enter the public IP, it doesn’t load. External clients can view the page through the public IP, but internal hosts cannot.
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
  ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
  ip nat inside

interface GigabitEthernet0/1
  ip address x.x.x.x 255.255.255.248
  ip nat outside

ip nat inside source static 192.168.1.4 189.195.132.78 route-map ROUTE_MAP

ip access-list extended ACL
  permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 host x.x.x.x

route-map ROUTE_MAP permit 10
  match ip address ACL

ip access-list standard LAN-TO-INTERNET
  permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255

ip nat inside source list LAN-TO-INTERNET interface GigabitEthernet0/1 overload

ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 x.x.x.x(gateway public ip)



if an internal network host (e.g., 192.168.1.10) tries to view the website hosted on the XAMPP server, it only loads when I enter the server's IP (192.168.1.4). If I enter the public IP, it doesn’t load.

That is quite normal. Using the external IP address from the private LAN requires the NAT router to both source NAT and then destination NAT to the server. That is not a normal operation mode and disabled by default.
You could enable hairpin NAT (usually with poor performance) but the much better solution is to use your internal DNS server to resolve the server's host name to the internal address, bypassing the router completely (split-brain DNS).
